# Assigning a value to a variable changes a session variable's value

Tags: php

One of my PHP pages, which runs on a remote server allegedly with PHP 5.2 installed, receives a POST request with a set "passcode" key and then, as it seems, the most strange things may happen. In the following code, "passcode" of the POST request is redefined to make value tracking simpler for you guys, but in tests it still produces the supernatural output indicated in the comments.

```
$_POST["passcode"] = "hi";
$_SESSION["passcode"] = "hello";

echo $_SESSION["passcode"] . '<br />'; // prints "hello"
$passcode = $_POST["passcode"];
echo $_SESSION["passcode"] . '<br />'; // prints "hi"
```

**EDIT:** So looks like it's about register_globals. Hence is another question:

Is there any way to turn this behavior off if I don't have access to the php.ini file on the server I'm running the code on?

Comment: With only that in the receiving file you have those results, or when it's through your entire, existing code?

Comment: That's odd.<br />
Is it the same when you comment out the fifth line?

Comment: @MetalFrog That POST receiving php file is the only place where I've tested it so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Smells like [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

If you can't edit your `php.ini` file, you can disable this setting in `.htaccess` file, as described [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals)

Answer (score 8):

Clearly, session variables are registered as globals.

Answer (score 2):

One possible reason it is possible is somewhere you have written

```
$_SESSION['passcode']=&$passcode;
```

Answer (score 2):

Session Variables may be configured to be handled as Global Varibales and so can be accessed through `$_SESSION["passcode"]` as well as `$passcode`. check your PHP Configuration (register_Globals)

Answer (score -1):

Change the name of the variable

```
$passcode
```

to something else.?

Comment: I'd rather change my hosting provider than my programming style.